# TYPO3 backend user without password

Tags: typo3

Is it save to create backend user with an empty password?

For example the `_cli_lowlevel` backend user or a backend user `editor-test`, which I only use for testing purposes via the "Switch to user" feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually a cli_* user should have no rights to access anything in the BE (non admin user, with no mount-points). it is used to execute TYPO3 by command line. if anyone can get access to a shell he can execute commands more dangerous than a simple BE-access. e.g. he can open access to the install-tool and create an admin-user. or use mysql-cli to set passwords to any given user.

normally you can not create BE-users without password as the form for BE-users requires a not empty password field. as you probably use salted and hashed passwords even a simple password can not be decrypted (so a brute force attack may find the password quickly). so the best way would be a long random password which you might forget the next moment.

Comment: Seems like this is broken in the actual master (TYPO3 8.5.0-dev). Creating a be user without password is possible.

Comment: Just for Information: creating a TYPO3 backend user without a password is already fixed in the core.